# Reduction of Subject Regarding Present Participle

Tags: participle-clauses, dangling-modifier

I have a question regarding **[Present Participle](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-participle/)**.

In the example below, I am wondering whether it is possible for the subject to be changed into an 'Empty Subject' *it*?

As I can see in the two listed uses of this website, the subjects for both clauses must be the same (and then one will be removed).

> Stopping only for gas, it took the truck driver nearly 12 hours to deliver the shipment of goods from Kansas City to Grand Rapids.

Sorry for the headline, I don't know how to make it clearer.

Comment: I forgot to post the link: [link] (http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-participle/)

Comment: That will be understood in ordinary speech or writing, but it is formally incorrect: you should write "Stopping only for gas, the truck driver took nearly 12 hours to deliver the shipment of goods from Kansas City to Grand Rapids."

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That's what I have thought of. It seems like the reduced subject of the first clause is not the same as that of the other clause.

Comment: You have understood this perfectly -- better, frankly, than most native-English writers!

Comment: I have just checked what you suggested me, **Dangling Modifier**. It explains my question greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping only for gas, the truck driver had taken  nearly 12 hours to deliver the shipment of goods from Kansas City to Grand Rapids.